# How to improve deep learning performance with using normalization and standarization?

Tags: python, keras, normalization

I have 8160 dataset, input's shape is (1500,1), output's shape is (2500,1). input's values are between -80 to 3. Outpur values vary between 0 or 1.

I thought that, normalization is applied to the input by using global maximum and global minimum. Then i realize, normalization is used for every specific input seperately by using local maximum and local minimum value of that input. Then i try both of them, and local normalization is gives much much better result.

I can't understand this. for example, by using local normalization, '0' corresponds to -20 for input 1, '0' corresponds to -80 for input 2. I think, usefull and comparative information about input 1 and input 2 is lost. Can someone help me to understand this, How can local normalization give better result? or is something wrong with my model? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Making it short: the optimisation of neural networks is usually performed using a gradient decent algorithm. Normalising or standardising your variables helps the algorithm to converge, as the size of the input features impacts the state size. A big variance in the features sizes

For more detail have a look [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/04/feature-scaling-machine-learning-normalization-standardization/) and [here](https://www.internalpointers.com/post/optimize-gradient-descent-algorithm).

As the author of the second link puts it:

> Using such unprocessed data as input features for a linear regression system might slow down the gradient descent algorithm to a crawl. It happens because [...] such not normalized data warps the cost function the gradient descent has to process, making the minimum point really difficult to reach.